# Can't use ansible server (on VM) for ping to EC2 client on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have one client (Ubuntu server) on EC2 AWS and one VM (Ansible server). I would like to use my ansible server ping to client on EC2.

So, I get the public key from EC2 and convert it to private key by PuttyGen.

and then I bring it to the ansible server.

I had config the ansible.cfg as below:

*private_key_file = /publickey/ansible.ppk*

and /ansible/hosts:

[aws]
*ec2-ip*

Then, I try command:

ansbile -m ping aws

and it was stuck. Nothing come

Anything I missed?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all you can't convert public key to private. And why do you think Ansible should honour putty key format?

Comment: I thought that private key is necessary to SSH remote to host on EC2. I got the key.pem from EC2 and I notice that is a public key. I don't know how to do this. So I use puttyGen to import key.pem and export the private key. Sorry I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved that.

By change permission of publickey

chmod 600 /path/to/key

It's work.